# How do I stop VBA userforms from extending beyond the window?

Tags: excel, vba, border, ms-forms

I am creating userforms in Excel. Every userform seems to extend 1-2 pixels too far to the right and bottom. Each form covers the 1 pixel black border surrounding each window, and it looks ugly. How can I stop all my userforms from extending too far to the right and bottom?

Right side of userform (NOT what I want): [image]

Left side of userform (What I want): [image]